# If $ S,T \in L(V_{1},V_{2}) $, then show that $ \ker(S) \subseteq \ker(T) $ if and only if $ T = P S $ for some $ P \in L(V_{2}) $.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $ V_{1} $ and $ V_{2} $ be finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $ \mathbb{K} $, and let $ S,T \in L(V_{1},V_{2}) $. Then show that $ \ker(S) \subseteq \ker(T) $ if and only if $ T = P S $ for some $ P \in L(V_{2}) $.

I have difficulty proving the converse: If $ \ker(S) \subseteq \ker(T) $, then $ T = P S $ for some $ P \in L(V_{2}) $.

I have defined an operator $ P: \text{im}(S) \to \text{im}(T) $ such that $ {P S}(u) = T(u) $. I have extended this operator to $ V_{2} $ in a manner that if $ u \notin \text{im}(S) $, then $ P(u) = 0 $.

Clearly, $ P $ is an operator on $ V_{2} $ and $ {P S}(u) = T(u) $. How can I prove that $ T(u) = PS(u) $?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) If $T=PS$ then $$ Sv=0\Rightarrow Tv=P(Sv)=0$$

(2) If $V_1$ has a basis $\{ e_i\}_{i=1}^n$ s.t. $
    Se_i=0\ 1\leq i\leq s$ and $\{ Se_i \}$ is linearly independent
    for $s+1\leq i\leq n $. And $V_2$ has a basis $\{ Se_i\} \cup \{
    f_i\}$. Then set $$
   P(Se_i)=T(e_i)\ s+1\leq i\leq n,\ P(f_i)=0 $$